# IOException when downloading file

Tags: android

Here is my simple code to download a file:

```
InputStream input = null;
        OutputStream output = null;
        try {
            URL fileURL = new URL(f.getVideoURL());
            URLConnection con = fileURL.openConnection();
            lengthOfContent = con.getContentLength();
            con.setConnectTimeout(10 * 1000);
            con.connect();

            input = new BufferedInputStream(fileURL.openStream());
            File f = new File("/sdcard/",fileName);
            if(!f.exists()){
                f.createNewFile();
            }else{
                f.delete();
                f.createNewFile();
            }
            output = new FileOutputStream(f);

            Log.v("FILE", fileName);

            byte[] data = new byte[2 * 1024];
            long tempBytesWritten = 0;


            while((tempBytesWritten=input.read(data))!=-1){
                bytesWritten.addAndGet(tempBytesWritten);
                output.write(data,0,(int)tempBytesWritten);
                synchronized(h){
                    h.post(new Runnable(){
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    });
                }
                output.flush();
                output.close();
                input.close();
            }
```

Although I connect using `con.connect()`, it says that BufferedInputStream is not open.
How do I make sure that it is open ??

```
08-06 19:45:12.070: W/System.err(9244): java.io.IOException: BufferedInputStream is closed
08-06 19:45:12.070: W/System.err(9244):     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.streamClosed(BufferedInputStream.java:118)
08-06 19:45:12.075: W/System.err(9244):     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:271)
08-06 19:45:12.075: W/System.err(9244):     at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:163)
08-06 19:45:12.075: W/System.err(9244):     at com.example.tqafragments.Task.run(Task.java:67)
08-06 19:45:12.080: W/System.err(9244):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: Set con.doInput(true) before content length. This should create the Input Stream.

Comment: Did you add permissions to write external storage to your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: @RaphaelAyres Tried. Same

Comment: @Procurares Yes, it creates an empty file, throws exception, returns

Comment: Instead of a simple URLConnection, cast it to a HttpUrlConnection, then check the response code with con.getResponseCode. The problem could be in the server, not only in your code. But you do need to setDoInput(true) in order to create the InputStream. And follow the answers. I have a code that does the same thing. You must pass con.getInputStream() to the constructor of BufferedInputStream

Comment: @RaphaelAyres I tried a few other URLs from where I can download. All gimme the same error. I am posting the satcktrace

Comment: @RaphaelAyres line 67 is: `(tempBytesWritten=input.read(data))!=-1`

Comment: @RaphaelAyres yaaay !! fixed it !!

Comment: Another thing you can do to boost it up is instead of using just read the Stream in chunks. Like this:  byte[] buffer = new byte[CHUNK_SIZE];        
int bytesRead = buf.read(buffer, 0, CHUNK_SIZE);  Set chunksize to 10 * 1024 or adjust it at your will to get better performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what is con.connected?

Have you tried opening the stream this way?

```
//remove con.connect();
input = new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());
```

Comment: The input stream is to be obtained from the `UrlConnection` or `HttpURLConnection` and not the `fileURL` ;)

Comment: opps I ment to say con.*, not fileurl.*

Comment: I just fixed the answer

Answer (score 1):

If i'm not wrong, you put `input.close()` in your while...

Comment: Oh sorry. They were are in the `finally` block. Moved them over there by mistake. The problem still persists :)

Comment: I thought it was weird too :D